Repair of 600GB table took 37 hours with reaper
I started using the Reaper tool to repair our Cassandra , the repair process is very slow .
I tested the tool on a 600GB table, and it took 37 hours to fully repair the table using the Reaper tool.
I have one replica in three data centers
My configuration
segmentCountPerNode: 16
repairParallelism: PARALLEL
repairIntensity: 0.9
scheduleDaysBetween: 7
repairRunThreadCount: 15
hangingRepairTimeoutMins: 30
storageType: cassandra
enableCrossOrigin: true
incrementalRepair: false
blacklistTwcsTables: true
enableDynamicSeedList: true
repairManagerSchedulingIntervalSeconds: 1
activateQueryLogger: false
jmxConnectionTimeoutInSeconds: 5
useAddressTranslator: false
maxParallelRepairs: 10

and 4 Repair Threads
I saw the following messages in the log, but i didn't see any pending compaction or busy nodes
INFO   [2024-07-19 04:01:50,862] [cassandra-staging:f3ba9f10-4449-11ef-bbc3-c35808c06f7a] i.c.s.RepairRunner - All nodes are busy or have too many pending compactions for the remaining candidate segments.
INFO   [2024-07-19 04:01:50,866] [cassandra-staging:f3ba9f10-4449-11ef-bbc3-c35808c06f7a] i.c.s.RepairRunner - All nodes are busy or have too many pending compactions for the remaining candidate segments.
INFO   [2024-07-19 04:01:50,873] [cassandra-staging:f3ba9f10-4449-11ef-bbc3-c35808c06f7a] i.c.s.RepairRunner - Repair amount done 216.0


Thanks for posting on Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to DBA Stack Exchange. For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

There isn't a lot to be analysed from the details you posted in your question that gives any indication for the cause of the problem.
One thing you could check is whether there are running repairs according to Reaper then compare those with the repair threads in progress on the nodes on the nodes. If there are other repair threads running on the nodes already (for example those which were manually triggered with nodetool repair that haven't completed yet, or other reasons), Reaper will be limited in initiating another repair.
As a side note, a scheduling interval of 1 second might be too aggressive on the backend since it will constantly request for the list of repair segments so you might want to consider a longer interval of 10 seconds. Cheers!
